# composer error symfony /finder

Tags: php, symfony

when i am trying to install new extension for magento i get the following error

what do i need to do in order to fix this?

```
  Problem 1
    - symfony/finder v3.4.1 requires php ^5.5.9|>=7.0.8 -> your PHP version (7.0.30-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) overriden by "config.platform.php" version (7.0.0) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - symfony/finder v3.4.1 requires php ^5.5.9|>=7.0.8 -> your PHP version (7.0.30-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) overriden by "config.platform.php" version (7.0.0) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - symfony/finder v3.4.1 requires php ^5.5.9|>=7.0.8 -> your PHP version (7.0.30-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) overriden by "config.platform.php" version (7.0.0) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - Installation request for symfony/finder == 3.4.1.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/finder[v3.4.1].
```

Comment: requires php ^5.5.9|>=7.0.8

Comment: Well it seems you have a config-section in your `composer.json` which fakes the PHP-version "7.0.0". If you remove that entry (or change it to 7.0.30) it should work.